# How to use CountA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to add to my macro, a rule that check if in Sheet1 in range A1:Z1 there are blank cells. If yes it runs further code. If not it will show MsgBox and stops macro. I wrote

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")) Then
 MsgBox"ERROR"
 
 Else

rest of my code

 End If
```

Unfortunately even those cells from A1:Z1 are blank i see MsgBox

Could you please help me?

Comment: add a `=26`.  COUNTA returns the count of non blank cells.

Comment: Very curious why you aren't using `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`?

Comment: @BigBen could you please help me how to use .CountBlank? I need something like If .CountBlank not equals to 0 than Msg BOX

Comment: That doesn't match the logic in your question but it's pretty easy to translate that to code.

Comment: `If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")) Then
 MsgBox"ERROR"` - error appears everytime. Even A1 Z1 is empty ...

Comment: CountBlank returns a number not a boolean:  `If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")) > 0 Then`

Comment: ok i did like this: ' If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")) > 0 Then MSG BOX "XXX" else WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z2")) > 0 THEN MSG BOX "XYZ" else REST OF MY CODE End if End if ' unfortunately it always stops at first count blank even range is fully blank :(

Comment: That means your cells *aren't* truly blank.

Comment: I have IF formula in those cells but the result of this formula is "" so it should be blank isnt it?

Comment: Can I transform somehow "" to blank?

Comment: I take my comment back. Can't repro. `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank` counts the number of cells in a range with a formula returning `""`.

Comment: So can I somehow make code which checks if in range A1:Z1 all cells have "". If yes it runs macro further if not it shows msgbox?

Comment: You can use COUNTIF or like the answer below iterate the range, though I would recommend using a variant array and iterating that, but below is a good start.

Comment: Could you show me example of use CountIF in my case, please?

Comment: A tip... get COUNTA, COUNTBLANK, or COUNTIF, whichever one you want to use, working as a formula in a cell on your sheet, *then* translate to code.

Answer (score 0):

I like to skip the worksheetfunctions and do pure VBA.

```
'set worksheet
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = worksheets("Sheet1")

'init counter
dim empty as integer
empty = 0


'loop cells
for x = 1 to 26
    'check row 1 columns 1 to 26
    if trim(ws.cells(1, x)) = "" then
        empty = empty + 1
    end if
next x

'check empty
if empty > 0 then
    'extra code
Else
    msgbox "no empty found"
end if
```

Comment: The worksheet function will be much quicker, especially when looking at large datasets.  If you were to do it this way use variant arrays and iterate that instead of iterating the range, which is the slowest methog

Comment: But it is a bad habit to fall into.   I will use variant arrays always when looping the data regardless of size.

Comment: Once you use a list in python, you would end up loathing VBA arrays. Redimming etc is the bane of my life.

Comment: When working with ranges you can bulk load an array without the need to use redim or redim preserve.